# How to set four virtual desktops in Windows 8.1 like Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8.1, desktop

I have started use Windows 8.1. I want to use four desktops like Ubuntu. It is possible?

Comment: Windows does not have this feature in any version of Windows ( at least not without [third-party programs](http://lifehacker.com/5358291/five-best-virtual-desktop-managers) ).

Comment: @Ramhound post this answer.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - What a product recommendation?  There are hundreds of questions on Superuser that already suggest those products and more.  We won't need another answer that repeats the exact same list of products.

Comment: only post "Windows does not have this feature in any version of Windows without using 3rd party tools" as answer, because this is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

windows has api for multidesktop, atleast windows 2008 and 7 had: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2006/07/05/656197.aspx

Microsoft has even program for it, no need for 3rd party stuff http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx  (tho, it was 3rd party software earlier)

Comment: Unfortunately, this application is crap, and I suspect the underlying API is as well (Sysinternals usually puts out good apps, afterall).  Therefore, while you're technically correct that this is a virtual desktop program... it is certainly not one worth using, leaving us with only 3rd party tools to achieve virtual desktops worth having on Windows.  Pity.

Comment: i use this application "Desktops v2.0" by microsoft as described by zakk, and its working good.